# Scala - method call syntax

Tags: scala, methods

I am a beginning practitioner in Scala and I saw a few different syntax for calling a method. Some are nice, as ignoring parenthesis for a parameterless method, or ignoring the dot as in

```
1 to 10
```

but some really puzzle me. for instance:

```
breakable { ... }
```

this is simply a method call right? Can I also do that for more than one parameter or a parameter which is not a parameterless function?

Thanks

Comment: yes, it is a closure. you are passing a code block into a method. Note that in Scala, you can use {} in place of () for single parameter passing to methods

Comment: What's bothering you here? Is it the code block (the `{...}`) part after the method name or the fact that we don't prefix the method with an object/class name?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two standard ways of calling methods:

```
obj.method(params)   // dot notation
obj method (params)  // operator notation
```

The above can be modified in the following ways:

1. If `params` is a single parameter, you can replace `()` with `{}`.
2. If `params` is a single parameter *and* you are using operator notation, you can drop the parenthesis.
3. If `method` doesn't take parameters, you can drop `(params)` (that is, drop the empty `()`).
4. If `method` ends with `:`, then it actually binds to the right *in operator notation*. That is, `(params) method_: obj` is equivalent to `obj.method_:(params)`.
5. Either way, spaces are optional as long as identifiers can be told apart. So one can add spaces to the dot notation, like `obj . method ( params )` or write `.method(params)` on the next line -- as often happens with call chaining --, as well as remove spaces from the operator notation, as in `a+b`.

There's also some stuff with tuple inference, but I try to avoid it, so I'm not sure of the exact rules.

None of these will explain the example you are confused about, however. Before I explain it, however, I'd like to show some syntactic sugars that can also be used to call methods:

```
obj(params) // equivalent to obj.apply(params)
obj.x = y   // equivalent to obj.x_=(y), if obj.x also exists
obj(x) = y  // equivalent to obj.update(x, y)
obj op= y   // equivalent to obj = obj op y, if op is symbolic
~obj        // equivalent to obj.unary_~; also for !, + and -, but no other symbol
```

Ok, now to the example you gave. One can *import* members of stable values. Java can do it for static methods with its static import, but Scala has a more general mechanism: importing from packages, objects or common instances is no different: it brings both type members and value members. Methods fall in the latter category.

So, imagine you have `val a = 2`, and you do `import a._`. That will bring into scope all of `Int` methods, so you can call them directly. You can't do `+(2)`, because that would be interpreted as a call to `unary_+`, but you could call `*(4)`, for example:

```
scala> val a = 2
a: Int = 2

scala> import a._
import a._

scala> *(4)
res16: Int = 8
```

Now, here's the rule. You can call

```
method(params)
```

If:

1. `method` was imported into scope.
2. You keep the parenthesis (even if there's only one parameter)

Note that there's a precedence issue as well. If you write `obj method(params)`, Scala will presume `method` belongs to `obj`, even if it was imported into scope.

Comment: Great answer. I just had a question about your point number 1, about being able to call a method with { } notation instead of (). Is there any specific reason this syntax is available? This syntax seems to be commonly used in many frameworks and their documented examples. I'm wondering if this particular syntax is supported for a very specific, functional reason. Is it generally used when passing closures as arguments to a function? I'd like to understand its roots so I can grasp and reason about it with clarity. Thanks.

Comment: @acspd7 Well, `()` and `{}` have different meanings inside an _expression_. That is, `2 * (3 + 4)` and `2 * { 3 + 4 }` have the same result, but are different things. You can only put expressions inside a parenthesis, whereas you put _definitions_ and _statements_ inside curly braces, and the value of the last statement is the expression value of it (curly braces are, themselves, an expression). The reason why `f(...)` can be replaced with `f{...}` is just so people don't have to write `f({...})`. That allows people to write "user" control structures that look native.

Answer (score 15):

If we desugar this we will have:

```
breakable({ ... })
```

this matches signature

```
breakable: (op: ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

and uses so named **call-by-name** arguments (you may think of this as *pass a block of code as argument*)

More over scala allows you to write this:

```
scala> def foo (op1: => Unit)(op2: => Unit) = {op1;op2;}
foo: (op1: => Unit)(op2: => Unit)Unit

scala> foo { println(1) } { println(2) }
1
2
```

Above is the example of curried function